# Div won't resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, height

CLOSED

I made it by switching 2 of the children to absolute, because they will never expand, than I putted the children whom size wont change to the top and than I moved the last one upwards by few pixels so it overlays and still can resize the parent.

Comment: can you publish sample codes on jsfiddle.net please ? Don't publish website's link. BEcause i couldn't find, which div you are talking about.

Comment: precisely because they have position absolute..

Comment: That's expected behavior. Absolute positioned child elements don't affect their parent

Comment: absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document "flow" and cannot affect the sizing/positioning of anything with the document. they basically become their own isolated little separate document within the page.

Comment: @David Debnar: That's what `absolute positioning` does. It removes the element out of the 'normal flow' of the document. Perhaps there is another solution. Can you please provide more info in stead of just a link to a website without telling us where it happens?

Comment: Alright I got it even from the first comment... So I will change the question, is it possible to adjust a divs height that has position relative due to the whole window, like position it 700px from the top?

Comment: Just in case you didn't get the previous 1000 comments saying the same thing, ABSOLUTE POSITIONED ELEMENTS DO NOT EFFECT THE SIZE OF THE PARENT ELEMENT.

Comment: David, yes it is just do position: relative; and top: 700px;

Comment: @Interstellar ... It doesn't work because top just ads pixels to the parents position.. I wan't to calculate the pixels from the top, so from the start of the <body>

Answer (score 1):

Elements that are absolutely positioned do not take up any space, so changes to the number or size of the children will have no effect on the size of the parent element.

If you want the parent container to expand/contract with its children, you need to float both the container and its children.

Comment: I don't think i agree with your second statement. Floating will not cause the container to expand/contract. If you did float them, then you would need to clear the float after the child elements.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: or use the `overflow: hidden;` hack

Comment: well, it would depend on some other constraints too, depending on how specific we are talking. EG if the parent had a width declared, then if the children did not all fit horizontally, they would automatically begin expanding the parent's vertical size. But from the OP question, I wasn't sure how specific to get.

Comment: So is it possible to calculate the "top: px;" from the total top of the page when the position is relative? I don't think so..Maybe I could just use some javascript that will hide'n'show some of the divs...

Comment: It's relative to the parent element.